# Ignore IRC messages based on contents in WeeChat

Tags: irc, weechat

I'm trying to figure out how to ignore messages in a buffer based on the contents of the message (NOT based on hostmask, user nick, etc.) in WeeChat.

Preferably, this would be able to utilize regex, but even ignoring based on single words would be fine.

Is there a plugin or way to do this in WeeChat itself?  I've been looking around and can't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use filter for this?

`/filter add ignore_spam irc.* irc_public spam.*spam`

Note you might want to add other tags to ignore things in PMs or actions.